# URL returns valid data/page in Chrome but not in Safari (or more importantly when called via Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, web-services, google-chrome, safari

I have an internally accessible url that you won't be able to access which might make this hard but I wanted to see if anyone had anything obvious that I am missing.  The url has been modified slightly but all of the components are still there.

http://subdomain.domain.com:9999/Command?auth=1a11111a1111a1a1111a111aa1a1aa11&email=email11@email.com&parameter=123

I'm calling the url using:

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest 
                      returningResponse:&response 
                                  error:&requestError];
```

I have using encoding for special characters like the @, all to no avail.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  It works in Chrome when simply entered in the url bar but not if entered in Safari in the url bar.

Comment: does Safari Error Console report any issues?

Comment: No errors are shown, just a blank page with no information.  The chrome page returned shows a beginning and end xml tag with a value in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to view source on Safari and saw the information that I was looking for there which caused me to go back to the code and see why the data wasn't being pulled out correctly.

I needed to look further into the code processing the web service call, turns out that the code was setup to only process JSON and the data I was looking for was being stripped out because it was XML.

I've documented this mostly in case it might be helpful to someone else as something they can look at.